# Timeout when submitting jobs to EC2 cluster

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I've been trying to make this work with no luck thus far.  I launch a cluster with

```
./spark-ec2 -k keyname -i ~/.keys/key.pem --region=us-east-1 -s 5 launch "my test cluster"
```

Then I submit a job with

```
bin/spark-submit --verbose --class com.company.jobs.AggregateCostDataWorkflow --master spark://ec2-54-157-122-49.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.executor.memory=5g /Users/my.name/scala-proj/target/scala-2.10/scala-proj-0.1.0.jar --outputPath,s3n://my-bucket/my-name/ec2-spark-test/
```

Where `outPutPath` is an argument to the main method.  After a bit and some status output, I see an exception that looks like

```
15/06/05 16:09:33 INFO StandaloneRestClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://ec2-74-141-162-19.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at [java socket stuff elided for brevity] org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.StandaloneRestClient.postJson(StandaloneRestClient.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.StandaloneRestClient.createSubmission(StandaloneRestClient.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.StandaloneRestClient$.run(StandaloneRestClient.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.StandaloneRestClient$.main(StandaloneRestClient.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.StandaloneRestClient.main(StandaloneRestClient.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

This is spark 1.3.1 (on my local machine)  I can access the UI on the master machine and verify that the Spark processes are in fact up.  I can also ssh into the master.

Any tips?

Comment: My knowledge of protocols is terribly rudimentary, and I'm not at work and can't test anything at the moment, but aren't Spark REST requests made on port 6066?  Do I need to ensure that the ec2 instances have that port open? See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/ec2/spark_ec2.py#L463.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open ports by editing security policies, if you want to access ports on your EC2 spark cluster. spark_ec2.py doesn't open ports 7077 and 6066 on master to be accessed from outside the cluster.

I use the other way - connect to master machine of your spark cluster with the command

```
./spark_ec2.py -k keyname -i ~/.keys/key.pem login "my test cluster"
```

Upload the your job file (with scp using same key) and submit job from there. This would ensure that your driver has access to a cluster master and slaves.

See "Running Applications" section of [Running Spark on EC2 documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html)

Comment: I tried adding the line `master_group.authorize('tcp', 6066, 6066, authorized_address)` - same error as before.  Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Again. Spark Amazon EC2 manual suggests submitting jobs from the after logging to master server via ssh.

Comment: If you want you can try submitting job after opening port 7077. I tried to create ec2 cluster and opening inbound TCP port 7077 - and was able to connect with `bin/spark-shell --master spark://ec2-54-159-17-215.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077`

Comment: Be careful though - by default spark_ec2 would open port 7077 for 0.0.0.0/0 - this will open this port to whole internet. I went to my EC2 management console web UI/Network & Security/Security Group and added inbound rule manually and set it to my computer's public IP.